# SAP Analysis from Excel

Tags: python, excel, sap-analysis-for-office

I need to make a script that will automatically open Excel with COM setting - SAP Analysis from Excel.
I am learning the language and so I could not find the solution myself on Github/Stackoverflow.
It started with a simple line of code, but eventually I found the solution below.
But when I load Excel, the Analysis add-in doesn't open in the file. However, if you open the Excel file without the script, the add-in appears.

```
import win32com.client as win32
from pathlib import Path

sap_aof_excel_file = Path.cwd().joinpath(r"C:\Users\alexandrovn\Desktop\mo\MO2022.xlsm")

bwclient = "CODE"
bwuser = "LOGIN"
bwpassword = "PASS"


excel_instance = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel_instance.Visible = True
excel_instance.DisplayAlerts = False

workbook_sap = excel_instance.Workbooks.Open(sap_aof_excel_file, False, False)

for addin in excel_instance.Application.COMAddIns:
    if addin.progID == 'SapExcelAddIn':
        if addin.Connect == False:
            addin.Connect = True
        elif addin.Connect == True:
            addin.Connect = False
            addin.Connect = True

lResult = excel_instance.Application.Run("SAPLogon", "DS_1", bwclient, bwuser, bwpassword)
lResult = excel_instance.Application.Run("SAPExecuteCommand", "RefreshData", "DS_1")

workbook_sap.Save
workbook_sap.Close()

excel_instance.DisplayAlerts = True
excel_instance.Application.Quit()

excel_instance = None
workbook_sap = None
```

But when you load Excel, the Analysis add-in does not open in the file. However, if you open the Excel file without the script, the add-in appears. This is the error that appears:

```
C:\Users\alexandrovn\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/alexandrovn/Desktop/mo/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alexandrovn\Desktop\mo\test.py", line 30, in <module>
    addin.Connect = True
  File "C:\Users\alexandrovn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 549, in __setattr__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(entry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 0, value)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Error.', (0, 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting', 'Failed to install the add-on.', None, 0, -2146233088), None)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Explain what the error is and how to start Excel with this add-in? Maybe there is an access problem (working via corporate network and no administrator rights on the PC)

Answer (score 1):

According to ['SAP'](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13077830/sap-analysis-for-excel-to-start-with-excel.html)

Excel won't load Add-Ins automatically when launching it via automation (your Python script will start Excel with the /automation and -embedding parameters) so you have to manually enable the Add-In which you should be able to achieve by adding following line to your script:

```
xl.COMAddIns("SAPExcelAddIn").Connect = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the code would persist the COM add-in. Better to take admin help and enable add-ins in AO